# Scrollable views custom coloured dots (Titanium)

Tags: titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

There doesn't seem to be a function to change the colour of the scrollable view dots. By default they are white, I want them to be blue.

How can I achieve this?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://gist.github.com/raulriera/2417902

This did the trick.

http://blog.foolprooflabs.com/2013/10/custom-paging-control-alloy-titanium-appcelerator/

Check this link out for information on how to implement the scrollableview.

Comment: thanks for linking to our blog :) Let us know if anything wasn't clear or you need further help